# Why the total number of levels of the recursion tree of a merge sort is lg n + 1?

Tags: performance, algorithm, recursion, mergesort

I think the question is pretty self-explanatory here but I am looking at "Introduction to Algorithms" 3rd edition page 37 and it says that the total # of levels of the recursion tree in Figure 2.5 is lg n + 1 but I do not understand why you have to +1. Can anyone please explain the rationale behind this? thanks

Comment: Try to check the validity by putting n = 2 or 4.

Comment: this is not merge sort specific... BTW the book will prove this later, just keep on reading.

Answer (score 3):

The tree should contain N leaves. A binary tree with level h( the root is level 1) has 2^(h-1) leaves at most, so we assert that 2^(h-1) >= n, that's h >= lg(n)+1. At the same time it should be a full binary tree. A full binary tree with level h will have (2^(h-2)+1) leaves at least, that's 2^(h-2)+1<=n, h<=lg(n-1)+2

When n=2^k, k+2>h>=k+1, so h=k+1=lg(n)+1, it's the case in the book.

What's more, when n!=2^k, there will be a k where 2^k>n>2(k-1),we have h>=lg(n)+1>k and h< lg(n)+2 < k+2, that's h = k+1 = ceil(lg(n)+1).

In all, k = ceil(lg(n)+1). where ceil(lg(n)+1) indicates the smallest integer which is not smaller than lg(n)+1.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say N is equal to 8. then, we have 4 levels:

```
1. full array with size 8.
2. halves with size 4.
3. quarters with size 2.
4. eighths with size 1.
```

That's lg n + 1. lg 8 = 3. lg 8 + 1 = 4.

Comment: Does that match the tree in the Figure?

Answer (score 0):

I have explained visually in detail how to calculate complexity of mergesort using recursion tree, have a look at it [here](http://2cupsoftech.wordpress.com/2014/03/24/visual-explanation-of-merge-sort-complexity/)

Answer (score 0):

The proposition

**"When the number of leaves is 2^n, the total number of levels in the tree is lg(2^n)+1"**

can be proven by induction, as introduced in the book.

Let's assume that the proposition holds for any 2^k >= 1. Based on our arbitrary assumption, when the number of leaves is 2^k, the total number of levels in the tree will be lg(2^k)+1 = k+1.

Then, what will be the total number of levels of the tree when the number of leaves is 2^(k+1)? In the tree we are dealing with here, every node except the leaf has two children, so the number of leaves in a tree with 2^(k+1) levels will be twice the number of leaves in a tree with k levels. This is because each level has twice as many nodes as the level above it.

Therefore, the level of a tree with 2^(k+1) leaves is 1 more than the level of a tree with 2^k leaves. In other words, the level of a tree with 2^(k+1) leaves is (k+1)+1. And since (k+1)+1 = lg(2^(k+1))+1, the given proposition holds.

When a proposition with the number of leaves is 2^(k+1) is shown to be true, the assumption about the proposition with the number of leaves in the previous step is 2^k was used. Therefore, we need to show that lg(2^k)+1 is true even when 2^k=1 (base case), that is, when the number of leaves is 1. If there is 1 node, of course the total number of levels is 1. And 1=lg1+1, so it holds true.

Therefore, the total number of levels of a perfect binary tree with 2^n leaves is lg(2^n)+1.